# charts js, doughnut chart not rendering tooptips correctly

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, graph-visualization

i have a multilevel donut chart but it is not rendering correctly here is code
the problem is, onmouseover on all green parts it says objects, on all grey parts it says products, solution i would like is, on outer ring it should say products, in middle objects, and inner most should be materials, grey areas should just show number. here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyzqkf6b/1/) of the problem
Code:

```
var op=93;
var ap=99;
var mp=66;
 var ctx = new Chart(myChart, {
        type: 'doughnut',

        data: {
            labels: ['Objects', 'Products', 'Materials'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Objects',
                data: [op, 100 - op],
                backgroundColor: ['#006a4e','#eeeeee'],
                hoverOffset: 4
            },{
                label: 'Products',
                data: [ap, 100 - ap],
                backgroundColor: ['#2e856e', '#eeeeee'],
                hoverOffset: 4
            },
                {
                    label: 'Materials',
                    data: [mp, 100 - mp],
                    backgroundColor: ['#5ca08e', '#eeeeee'],
                    hoverOffset: 4
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            //cutoutPercentage: 40,
            height: 200,
            width:200

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that fairly simple with Chart.JS 2.7.2. Add `labels` to each dataset like this:

```js
data: {
  labels: ['Existing', 'Non'],
  datasets: [
    {
      labels: ['Objects', 'Non-objects'],
      ...
    }, {
      labels: ['Products', 'Non-products'],
      ...
    },
    {
      labels: ['Materials', 'Non-materials'],
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

And add the following label tooltip callback:

```js
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
      var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
      var index = tooltipItem.index;
      return dataset.labels[index] + ": " + dataset.data[index];
    }
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/fxd6vops/3/

I am sure it is possible with Chart.JS > 3.0 too but I have no idea how since quite a few things changed in the structure.

Comment: you are a life saver, can you please add a click function, it only should show which ring clicked

Comment: That's a different setting called `events`. By default `["mousemove", "touchstart", "touchmove", "click"]`, you can set it to `["click"']` so that only clicks trigger tooltips. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/adelriosantiago/fxd6vops/5/

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem which took a lot of time but what worked in the end was importing these elements and initialising them ..

**import { Chart as ChartJS, ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend } from 'chart.js';
ChartJS.register(ArcElement, Tooltip, Legend);**

these are the elements that helps make the entire chart. you can't skip them